# preg_replace_callback alternative of preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am currently using

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', '_', $str)
```

what would be the alternative function using preg_replace_callback?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? This would only call an unnecessary function call which you don't need here

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/) You already have most parts (esp. the regex), a function that returns `'_'` shouldn't be too difficult to implement - or is it?

Comment: Yes, can you please do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it myself

```html
function url_title($mystr){
 $result = '';
 $result .= preg_replace_callback(
                '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/',
                function ($matches) { return '_'; }, 
                $mystr);
      
 return strtolower($result);
}

$mystr = "some string here";
echo url_title($mystr);
```